# Troubleshooting Vacuum Roller Motor

Tags: diodes, motor, rectifier, triac

I am trying to repair a vacuum so that the carpet roller will work again (motor does not run). I have disassembled the head of the vacuum and found what is probably a fairly simple electronics board but I don't have much experience with such things. What I do know is that around 110vac goes in the black and white wires, and around 0.7vac goes to the motor via the black and red wires, and the motor does not run. I believe this is the root of the issue as I am pretty sure that it's a DC motor. I unsoldered the motor and connected it directly to a 22v battery and the motor seems to run fine from that source. The board has an indicator light to "check roller" that is on. I thought I had found a bad diode, D2, because I was getting some strange readings (ohms across it both ways) from it compared to the other two on the board, D1 and D3, but replacing that diode didn't do anything. I don't know enough about electronics to know for sure if the board is meant to take AC and convert it to DC for the roller motor, or if the issue is that the board is getting AC in the first place. I don't have any schematics for this of course, but I have attached some pictures that will hopefully be enough to help diagnose this. Please let me know if additional pictures could help or if there are any simple checks I can do with a multimeter that might help. Thank you.

[image: Full circuit, black and white wires plug into vacuum via pins]
[image: Back of board]
[image: Front of board]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.